# Unable to use up arrow key in screen copy mode or windowlist

Tags: gnu-screen, arrow-keys

I am ssh'ing from a terminal window on my Mac to a NetBSD box (our bastion host) and then running screen on the NetBSD box.

In copy mode or in the windowlist (which uses the copymode key bindings), I can use the 'hjkl' keys for cursor movement, and I can use 3 of the 4 arrows, but not up arrow.  I believe I have found the cause with `^A:bindkey -m` which says:

> :kF:               -> stuff ^D
>    :kR:               -> stuff ^U
>    :kh:               -> stuff \201
>    :kH:               -> stuff \205
>    :kN:               -> stuff ^F
>    :kP:               -> stuff ^B
>    **:ku:               -> stuff ^@**
>    :kd:               -> stuff \216
>    :kr:               -> stuff \206
>    :kl:               -> stuff \202

However, I don't seem to be able to override the `:ku:` binding.
Trying to change it:

```
bindkey -m :ku: stuff \220
```

just adds a new useless binding at the end of the list, but trying to delete the original one with:

```
bindkey -m :ku:
```

does nothing.

**Is there some way I can fix this?**

> Notes:
>
> > Mac:
> >
> > > OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)
> > >       $TERM = xterm-256color
> >
> > NetBSD:
> >
> > > 6.1.2
> > >       $TERM = xterm-256color
> > >       There appears to be no system screenrc
> > >       My .screenrc says only: defscrollback 8192